# Tables and ::nth child

Tags: html, css

I have two different tables. I set text-center in all rows and cells but In one table I must to have last td and th like this :

```
tr:last-child > td:first-child {
text-align: right;
}

tr:last-child {
font-weight: 900;
}
```

And it works well, but to all my tables I create. In the second I want to be default  td and tr, but it takes my earlier css with right text-align and font-weight. 
How to do, to my css work only in one table? Not all?

Comment: Add a class to the table you want it on and use that selector.

Comment: `table:first-of-type ...`?

Comment: @Templar My god! So easy... Thx!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

add some class to your tables and use it to define the css rule. Define the specific rule for the class that you wanna to.

instead tr:last-child, use .tableClassName:last-child